# How to add items to admin menu?

Tags: module, magento-1, xml, menu

Maybe its a simple question, but not for beginners :) . How can I add item to the admin menu? also with submenus in magento ?
I created a module, which have the following structure
[image]

the content of config.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Netgroup_Attributegrouping>
             <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Netgroup_Attributegrouping>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and the content of adminhtml.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<menu>
    <attributegrouping translate="title" module="attributegrouping">
        <title>AttributeGrouping</title>
        <sort_order>210</sort_order>
    </attributegrouping> 
</menu>
</config>
```

and the content of Helper/Data.php is:

```
<?php

class Netgroup_Attributegrouping_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

the file from modules/Netgroup_AttributeGrouping.xml content is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Netgroup_Attributegrouping>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Netgroup_Attributegrouping>
    </modules>
</config>
```

BUT the result is nothing. What should I do ? thx

Comment: Did you see your module name appear in System > Configuration > Advanced?

Comment: Now I am getting this: Fatal error: Class 'Mage_AttributeGrouping_Helper_Data' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\dachim\app\Mage.php on line 546

Comment: I think it is because a problem with the module name. You may try to use the name as Attributegrouping instead of AttributeGrouping. You should make it the same for everywhere.

Comment: I change the name as you suggested everywhere  in admin.xml, config.xml, Netgroup_Attributegrouping.xml and also the name of the folders, but i got the same error message

Comment: Please make sure that you disable cache and compilation.

Comment: yes i clear my cache after every changes. Please check my post again, i updated it, also the image. I still got this: Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Attributegrouping_Helper_Data' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\dachim\app\Mage.php on line 546

Comment: ok , I removed this part: module="attributegrouping" from adminhtml.xml and it is working . the question is why?

Comment: When you remove that, it will not call the helper. So the issue is gone. You should check why the Helper file is not defined.

Comment: In config.xml, you should add the following thing: 
<helpers>
      `<attributegrouping>
        <class>Netgroup_Attributegrouping_Helper</class>
      </attributegrouping>
    </helpers>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice you did not defind Helper in config.xml 
So you should add the following thing:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
      <attributegrouping>
        <class>Netgroup_Attributegrouping_Helper</class>
      </attributegrouping>
    </helpers>
</global>
```