# Custom admin menu item not displaying

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, adminmenu

I know this question has been asked before, but no matter what I try, it's not displaying. It doesn't break and there's no error. The admin menu just renders as if I had done nothing.

- I've tried this extensive [tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited)
- I also tried using [this as a guide](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29973/how-to-add-items-to-admin-menu)

Is it because I'm using version 1.9.1? I know the tutorial is rather old and after researching, it seems a lot of things changed in 1.9. I've been adding my files and folders to `/app/code/community/`. Do I also need anything in the `/app/code/local/` or `/app/etc/modules/`?

I've tried the tutorial step by step multiple times. Even just copying and pasting directly from the page. Same goes for the second link. I haven't had much luck on finding anything regarding this and version 1.9 specifically and I'm pretty new to Magento.

Would somebody be able to steer me in the right direction to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you share your current code?